# Change the color of the word THIS on vsc

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know the correct format to change the color of "THIS."

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Pro (Filter Spectrum)]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "this",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "italic",
                    "foreground": "#c50000"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: i did it, using the tools "TextMate Scope Inspector Widget" https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I was trying to figure this out and came across a solution that worked for me. So, for anyone else looking:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope":"variable.language.this",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ffa7a7",
                    "fontStyle": "italic"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```